# Imprimir table generada dinámicamente con PHP en un PDF

Tags: php, pdf

Estoy intentando imprimir una tabla que genero dinámicamente en un PDF. Según los datos que tengo, puede que necesite combinar varias celdas, eso está resuelto, el problema es que la solución que he encontrado me deja uno o varios `<tr>` vacíos (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12560991)

Cuando imprimo la tabla en el navegador funciona correctamente, pero al hacerlo en el PDF se rompe todo, pues evidentemente no debería existir un `<tr>` vacío.

El código que tengo es el siguiente (Laravel Blade)

```
<?php
    <tbody>
        @foreach ( $table_data as $row )
            <tr>
            @if (count($row) > 1)
                <td rowspan="{{ count($row) }}">{{ $row[0]->receipt_number }}</td>
                <td rowspan="{{ count($row) }}">
                    @foreach ($view_data['subtotal'] as $key => $sub)
                        @if ($sub->check_number == $row[0]->receipt_number)
                            {{number_format($sub->subtotal, 2)}}
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            @else
                <td>{{ $row[0]->receipt_number }}</td>
                <td>
                    @foreach ($view_data['subtotal'] as $key => $sub)
                        @if ($sub->check_number == $value->receipt_number)
                            {{number_format($sub->subtotal, 2)}}
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            @endif
                @foreach ( $row as $value )
                    <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->manual_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->customer_name.' '.$value->customer_surname}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->code}}</td>
                    <td>{{ number_format($value->amount, 2)}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->bank}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->collect_way}}</td>
                </tr><tr>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
?>
```

Los datos procesados vienen en la variable `$table_data` y vienen de la siguiente manera

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [receipt_number] => 4
                    [id] => 2
                    [manual_date] => 2020-03-28
                    [customer_name] => Customer 2
                    [customer_surname] => Test
                    [code] => er44
                    [amount] => 15
                    [bank] => Banco 4
                    [collect_way] => Forma de cobro 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [receipt_number] => 4
                    [id] => 2
                    [manual_date] => 2020-03-28
                    [customer_name] => Customer 2
                    [customer_surname] => Test
                    [code] => 3131
                    [amount] => 15
                    [bank] => Banco 4
                    [collect_way] => Forma de cobro 1
                )

        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [receipt_number] => 0
                    [id] => 6
                    [manual_date] => 2020-03-30
                    [customer_name] => Customer 2
                    [customer_surname] => Test
                    [code] => 3131
                    [amount] => 35.5
                    [bank] => Banco 1
                    [collect_way] => Cheque aseguradora
                )

        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [receipt_number] => 22
                    [id] => 7
                    [manual_date] => 2020-03-30
                    [customer_name] => Customer 2
                    [customer_surname] => Test
                    [code] => er44
                    [amount] => 44
                    [bank] => Banco 4
                    [collect_way] => Cheque aseguradora
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [receipt_number] => 22
                    [id] => 7
                    [manual_date] => 2020-03-30
                    [customer_name] => Customer 2
                    [customer_surname] => Test
                    [code] => 3131
                    [amount] => 44
                    [bank] => Banco 4
                    [collect_way] => Cheque aseguradora
                )

        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [receipt_number] => 13
                    [id] => 11
                    [manual_date] => 2020-04-05
                    [customer_name] => Customer 1
                    [customer_surname] => Apellido 1
                    [code] => 3131
                    [amount] => 25.5
                    [bank] => Banco 1
                    [collect_way] => En cheque
                )

        )

)
```

Adjunto una imagen para que se entienda mejor qué es lo que pasa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución y además he simplificado el código y ha quedado de la siguiente manera

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ( $rows as $row )
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="{{ count($row) }}">{{ $row[0]->receipt_number }}</td>
            <td rowspan="{{ count($row) }}">
                @foreach ($view_data['subtotal'] as $key => $sub)
                    @if ($sub->check_number == $row[0]->receipt_number)
                        {{number_format($sub->subtotal, 2)}}
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </td>
            @for ($i = 0; $i < count($row);)
                <td>{{ $row[$i]->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row[$i]->manual_date}}</td>
                <td>{{ $row[$i]->customer_name.' '.$row[$i]->customer_surname}}</td>
                <td>{{ $row[$i]->code}}</td>
                <td>{{ number_format($row[$i]->amount, 2)}}</td>
                <td>{{ $row[$i]->bank}}</td>
                <td>{{ $row[$i]->collect_way}}</td>
                // Verificamos si es necesario añadir estas etiquetas o no
                @if( count($row) !== ++$i ) </tr><tr> @endif
            @endfor
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```